# Animation VR using html (why is my shape not moving)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, aframe, virtual-reality

I'm creating a shooting game and I want the shapes to move from left to right and repeat until the shape is destroyed (but for a reason that I don't know it is not working the shape is staying still)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component@1.1.0/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codechangers.com/physics.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <a-scene id="myScene">
    <a-entity environment="preset:dream;"></a-entity>
    <a-plane id="floor" static-body height="1000" width="1000" position="0 -0.02 0" color="black" rotation="-90 0 0">
    </a-plane>
    <a-camera id="myCamera" position="0 1 0">
      <a-cursor intersection-spawn="event: click; mixin: voxel"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>



    <a-octahedron static-body class="target" color="white" radius="1" position="6 3 -5"></a-octahedron>

    <a-octahedronstatic-body class="target" color="black" radius="1" position="4 6 -5"
      animation="property: position; to: 10 3 -5; easing: linear; loop:true; dur:1600"></a-octahedron>
      
    <a-box static-body class="target" color="white" radius="1" position="-2 3 -5"></a-box>

    <a-octahedron static-body class="target" color="white" radius="1" position="2 3 -5"></a-octahedron>



  </a-scene>
</body>
<script src="https://codechangers.com/camps2019/vr/shoot-partial.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>nextlevel = 'level2.html';</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You're in an old A-Frame version. Use https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js

Answer (score 0):

[a-frame 0.7.0 used `<a-animation>`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/animations.html#sidebar) for animations,
since a-frame 0.9.0 a-frame switched to using the [`animation`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#sidebar) component (like in your code)

Either use the [newest a-frame version](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/) (preferably), or if for some reason you can't change the version then you'll need to use `<a-animation>` instead of the `animation` component.